How to preserve original icon colors in Shell
Tabbar within a MAUI Shell control has built-in functionality to set tint to selected/unselected icons in bottom bar. Therefore all icons have mono color.
My goal is to highlight background preserving original icons / use two different icons on selected/unselected tabs.
I managed to remove tint on iOS using custom IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker, but cannot figure out Android and Windows version.


Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Did you mean you want to keep the icon color on the shell tabbar? In addition, you said: I managed to remove tint on iOS using custom ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker. But the ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker is used in Android not iOS.

@Liyun Zhang, my bad, copied from the wrong file. I was experimenting with ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker for Android and cannot find a solution yet. And  yes, I want to preserve color like I did in the toolbar and ideally have some way to highlight background.


For the Android, you can use the ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker to do that.

Declare the color in the \Platforms\Android\Resource\values\colors.xml:
<color name="unselected">#ffffff</color>
<color name="selected">#264813</color>

Create the \Platforms\Android\Resource\drawable folder and create the drawable_selector file in it:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_checked="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@color/unselected"/>
</selector>

And then use it in the ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker:
public class MyShellRender : ShellRenderer
 {
     protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
     {
         return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
     }
 }
 public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
 {
     public void Dispose()
     {
     }

     public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
     {
     }

     public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
     {
         bottomView.ItemIconTintList = null;
         var menu = bottomView.Menu;
         var first = menu.GetItem(0);
         first.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.firstimage);
         var second = menu.GetItem(1);
         second.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.secondimage);
         bottomView.ItemBackground = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(Platform.CurrentActivity,Resource.Drawable.drawable_selector);
     }
 }


For the iOS, you can use custom IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker to do that:

 public class MyShellRender : ShellRenderer
 {
     protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
     {
         return new CustomTabBarAppearance();
     }
 }
 public class CustomTabBarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
 {
     public void Dispose()
     {
     }

     public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
     {
     }

     public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
     {
         var tabbar = controller.TabBar;
         if (tabbar.Items != null)
         {
             var item1 = tabbar.Items[0];
             item1.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("first.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
             var item2 = tabbar.Items[1];
             item1.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("second.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
         }

     }

But there is no api can change the background color of the selected item on the iOS.

Finally, for the Windows: the platformview is navigationview, but maui custom the MenuItemTemplate, and not support the color image. So you can try to use OnPlatform to set special image for the windows. Or you can report this on the github repo.


Yes, that works. Also in addition, for android you can just inherit existing ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker, override SetAppearance, call base.SetAppearance and nullify ItemIconTintList after that, if you don't want to manage all items manually every time.
